# Android pass custom arrayList with bundle

Tags: android

This my array list:

```
 private List<myclass> arrList = new ArrayList<myclass>();
```

### My code:

```
public class myclass implements Serializable {

private int user_id;
private String fname;
private String EditVal;

public myclass() {

}

public myclass(String fname, int user_id, String EditVal) {  
    this.user_id = user_id;
    this.fname = fname;
    this.EditVal = EditVal;
}


public String getFname(){
    return fname;
}

public String EditVal(){
    return EditVal;
}

}
```

Now in activity I want to add item to array list and pass it with bundle

```
    Bundle outState = new Bundle ();

    myclass r = new myclass("medo medo",40, TxtVal);
    arrList.add(r);
    outState.putSerializable("savedList",  arrList);
```

But its give me and error

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcelable encountered IOException writing serializable object
>
> Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException

Comment: You should add the whole stack-trace.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the ArrayList of your own class if it implements **Serializable** or **Parcelable**.
This is due to the fact that it is serialized and "compressed" into the bundle.

```
Bundle outState = new Bundle ();

myclass r = new myclass("medo medo",40, TxtVal);
arrList.add(r);
// outState.putSerializable("savedList",  arrList);
outState.putParcelableArrayList("savedList", arraylist);
```

Regards,

Comment: look to my class i used `public class myclass implements Serializable`

Comment: Yes, I saw that. I just said it on the comment that it must implement either Serializable or Parcelable so that other people reading the thread know it is mandatory :) 
Either way, did it work?